# Typesafe config programmatic modification and persistence

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

Typesafe Config documentation and library examples make a point that type safety can be achieved by making a configuration object or nested objects with getter methods mapped to `Config.getType(key)` methods.

If I wrap config calls in something like this:

```
class MyConfig (cfg:Config) {
  val language = cfg.getString("app.language")
  val database = new {
     val url = cfg.getString("db.url")
     val port = cfg.getInt("db.port")
     ...
  }
}
```

I can do decent looking calls like `config.database.url`. Neat. (That dot looks so much greater than underscore)

What I don't quite get is how to allow modifying properties and saving them - quoting documentation, config is immutable. My attempts so far turned into either a gross spaghetti (closures with `var config`) or horrendous boilerplate (modifying a plain object and creating a new config from it to save), so I turned here for help.

I'd appreciate if someone showed me a good pattern for programmatically modifiable configuration using Typesafe Config.

*It is possible that Typesafe Config just isn't a right tool for the job. I have little use for it's powerful merging and inheritance capabilities, instead I mostly need a simple, concise, unicode-friendly and type-safe way to load and store properties. I already do have one, a reflection-based java lib working with annotated POJOs. Doesn't seem to be a lot of variety with configuration libraries in Scala. I may have been too eager to throw away my trusty java tools.*

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on the use case where you'd like to modify the config? I can hardly think of a situation where you'd like to repoint your database connection at runtime to some URL not known at the start of the application.

Comment: @Norbert This is a web application, and some things should be configurable after deployment, even if only once. I gave some stretched example.. The db in question is an auxiliary db for some statistics stuff - this was probably misleading and unrelated to my question. What is related, however, is that things should be configurable with administrative UI, not by digging through text files on a server.

Comment: config is a file ... type safe config is for reading configs from it ... need to modify the file ? just do it (not with type-safe config)

Comment: @Nimrod007 Yes, it is probably the simplest way with saving a ```String->String``` map to properties file, but breaking DRY principle (loading properties by name in one place; making a map of them in another) can make things less manageable. Serializing an object as JSON is also an option, but would bring in some dependencies. Both way would work I guess, but begs the question: given that saving application settings modified by that application UI is a 100% common situation - what would be an 'idiomatic' scala way to do it?

Comment: in my opinion if you need constant changes in any kind on values (setting , or whatever the user is changing) the application.conf file and typesafe config is not your tool. save in another data structure (DB / cache / file / memory) and dynamically read / reload what you need. this is not related to DRY just with tool choice :)